# phpmyadmin load error in xampp

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

I am using windows xp sp2 and xampp version 1.8.0. the apache and mysql services are running but i cant access the localhost/phpmyadmin am getting this error:

Cannot start session without errors, please check errors given in your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly.

how can this problem be fixed?

Comment: Are there an errors in your log file? Check `\xampp\apache\logs\error.log`

Comment: Well, why don't you follow the suggestion of the error message first?

Comment: @hakre i have followed the suggestions several times, did a re-installation of the xampp but no success. i can access the mysql using the xampp_shell

Comment: *"please check errors given in your PHP and/or webserver log file"* -> what did you found in these files? Add your findings to your question.

Comment: @doublesharp this is what is in the apache/logs/error.log file.[Mon Oct 15 16:18:45.578125 2012] [ssl:warn] [pid 2668:tid 1884] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be due to either a client-sided issue with cookies, or a server-sided issue relating to permissions of the temporary directory where session files are stored. 
Client sided solution

This error can simply be an issue with cookies in your web browser, so either delete all stored cookies or selectively delete them for just the domain/directory where phpMyAdmin is if your browser allows this.

For example, in the current version of Google Chrome at the time of writing this post, you can go into the preferences then select Under the Hood -> Content Settings -> All Cookies and Site Data and then type the domain into the "Search cookies" input box. Then hover over the domain in question and click the X delete button. (Alternatively you could do this via the developer tools).